# Query regarding manuscript submission

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I recently submitted a manuscript to the Journal of Number theory following all its norms. But after submission I noticed a small mistake I made while writing a formula. The proof isn't wrong but I misinterpreted the formula in Latex.(I made a minor typo)

Now I noticed and corrected the manuscript. Can I do something about it?

Answer (score -1):

We're all been there. Three questions:

1. Is it really a "minor typo"?
2. Does it affect the understanding of what follows?
3. Is it reasonably easy for the reader to figure out the correct formula?

If the answers are yes, no, yes, then I'd leave things as they are, for the moment. There will be plenty of opportunities during revision.

Comment: I disagree. If you can correct it, you should. This paper has not been accepted or published yet, so there is plenty of time to make the correction. Leaving things as they are will annoy readers and waste their time. Perhaps "we've all been there" in the sense that we have all made minor errors, but that does not mean it is OK to leave an error in the paper when you can easily fix it.

Comment: "This paper has not been accepted or published yet, so there is plenty of time to make the correction." That was exactly my point. There will be at least one round of revision.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Wait till the journal sends it back asking for revisions, and make the correction then. Or if they reject it, make the correction before you submit it to a new journal.

Comment: My answer was implying exactly that. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Your editor will not be pleased, but you should tell them what you discovered with a profuse apology and the new version.  You are not the first one in the same predicament.

Comment: The editor will not be as displeased as this answer suggests, and you don't need to give a profuse apology. You just need to wait till the reviewers' comments come and correct the error then.

Comment: I disagree. A referee that is very good will go through all the equations, and needs to make an adjustment that this is indeed a typo. Given that mathematical papers are written in a very dense style, this is not quite trivial. So, as editor I need to send the correction to the reviewer. This can be done manually, or by using the software provided by the editor. Neither is trivial and imposes on the editor's time.